# Send data to speak dialogue

Tags: pipelines, speak

I am opening a speak dialog from a custom step that I have introduced to the uiDeleteItems pipeline.
How can I get access to data from the pipeline (fx the items being deleted) in the javascript code of the dialogue?

In my pipeline step I open the dialog like this:

```
SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(new ModalDialogOptions("/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/MyCustomDialog")
    {
        Width = "400",
        Height = "800",
        Response = true,
        ForceDialogSize = true,
        Message = args.Parameters["items"] //this was an attempt to pass data..
    });
```

I was hoping that I somehow could acces the Message with the item ids. But I can't find a property on the dialog that gives me access to the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only way, is to pass values through the QueryString. If you need a item in your dialog, you could pass the id:

```
Sitecore.Text.UrlString _url = new  Sitecore.Text.UrlString(Url);
url.Append("id", args.Parameters["id"]);
SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(_url.ToString());
```

And then get the item form the database in your modal dialog.